# Pass url params hash in controller to another method, becomes nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a route that matches `/edit_account => accounts#edit` since the account id isn't provided it's supposed to use the current user id and the `account#edit` method is shared with `/accounts/[:id]/edit`.

```
class AccountController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def edit
    # This doesn't work:
    params = retrieve_id_if_missing(params)

    # This works:
    # aHash = params
    # params = retrieve_id_if_missing(aHash)
  end

  def retrieve_id_if_missing(params)
    # raise params.inpect => returns nil at this point
    if params[:id].nil? and !logged_in?
      redirect_to root_path
    else params[:id].nil?
      params[:id] = current_user.id
    end
      params
  end
end
```

The problem I am having is that `params`, when passed to the class method, `retrieve_id_if_missing`, is becoming `nil`. However, if I assign `params` to another variable. e.g., `aHash`, before passing it to `retrieve_id_if_missing` it will contain the expected data, `{"action" => "edit", "controller" => "account"}`.

I've tried to search for a reason but have come up short, can someone explain to me why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ruby interpreter is treating `params` as a local variable and initializing it with `nil` when it sees the assignment. This happens before it executes the `retrieve_id_if_missing`.

This is why explicitly assigning a value to the local variable before calling the method avoids the error, because the initialization to `nil` by Ruby doesn't happen.

The following examples demonstrate this:

**Example #1**

```
def foo(bar)
  puts "foo bar: #{bar.class}"
end
bar = foo(bar) # => nil
puts "bar: #{bar.class}"

# Outputs: 
#     foo bar: NilClass 
#     bar: bar: NilClass
```

**Example #2**

```
a = a # => nil
puts "a: #{a.class}"

# Outputs: 
#    a: NilClass
```

**Example #3**

```
a = 123 if a # => nil
puts "a: #{a.class}"

# Outputs: 
#    a: NilClass
```

References:

[Why is `a = a` `nil` in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908050/why-is-a-a-nil-in-ruby)

> Ruby interpreter initializes a local variable with nil when it sees an
>   assignment to it. It initializes the local variable before it executes
>   the assignment expression or even when the assignment is not reachable
>   (as in the example below). This means your code initializes a with nil
>   and then the expression a = nil will evaluate to the right hand value.
>
> a = 1 if false a.nil? # => true The first assignment expression is not
>   executed, but a is initialized with nil.

[Ruby: method inexplicably overwritten and set to nil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20225072/37966)

> Here's another example:
>
> a = 123 if a  # => nil a  # => nil We shouldn't be able to say if a
>   because we never set a, but Ruby sees the a = 123 and initializes a,
>   then gets to if a at which point a is nil
>
> I'd consider it a quirk of the interpreter, really. Gary Bernhardt
>   makes fun of it in wat (https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat)
>   with a = a

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
class AccountController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def edit

    retrieve_id_if_missing


  end

  def retrieve_id_if_missing()
    if params[:id].nil? and !logged_in?
      redirect_to root_path
    else params[:id].nil?
      params[:id] = current_user.id
    end
      params
  end
end
```

I am fairly sure params will be in scope in the method.

Anyhow, check out gem devise for this.  it should have everything you want and more

With devise you can just use

```
before_filer :authenticate_user!
```

At the top of your controller

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Comment: While this works and is definitely cleaner, I still don't understand why it is behaving the way it is as explained in my question. Note: this is not production code (or ever will be) so I'm not interested in  using the right gem right now.

Comment: I am not 100% sure of the mechanics but ruby passes variables by reference.  So you are passing a reference to params into the function and the function is then is passing the reference to the same object back to overrite that object.  Perhaps in that chain ruby is creating a new nil object to get round the issue.

Answer (score 0):

While I cannot answer why your params object would be overridden with the code provided, here are some thoughts.

```
class AccountController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :retrieve_id_if_missing, only: :edit

  def edit
    # You'll find params[:id] prepopulated if it comes here,
    # else the request has been redirect
  end

protected

  # There should be no need to pass the params object around, it should be accessible everywhere
  def retrieve_id_if_missing
    if logged_in?
      params[:id] ||= current_user.id # conditional assignment will only happen if params[:id] is nil
    end

    # Redirect to root if params[:id] is still blank, 
    # i.e. user is not logged in and :id was not provided through route
    if params[:id].blank?
      flash[:alert] = 'You need to be logged in to access this resource.'
      return redirect_to root_url # early return!
    end
  end
end
```